# Keep SOT-223 tab unrouted in EasyEDA - is it possible?

Tags: pcb-design

I have SOT-223 component wich has internal connection between the tab and its 2-nd pin:

[image]

I'd like to keep it unconnected on the PCB (just to make it possible to pass another traces under the component). These pins will still be connected internally but Design Rule Checker will report these errors.

Is it possible to avoid?

Comment: Is there no options to ignore this specific error? (Eagle has "approve error" thing)

Comment: Why can't you just route over the top, essentially through the "Q1" silkscreen?

Comment: @Ilya I can ignore that. I'm just looking for a better solution if it exist.

Comment: @RomanMatveev not you ignore that. Tell the program to ignore this specific error so when checkin for errors it won't be in the error list anymore

Answer (score 1):

Does the schematic symbol have all four pins or just the functional three?

If three, you could remake the footprint, making a distinction between pin 2 and the tab, and then make sure the schematic symbol matches.

Edit: added image for illustration.

[image]

Although pins 2 and 4 are functionally the same, their unique numbering means they will not be electrically connected unless I connect them on the schematic.

I made this footprint in Altium, I'm unsure about the capabilities of EasyEDA, but I would imagine it's possible to edit or add custom footprints.

Alternatively, you could run a trace around the top of Q1 (past pin 3, under the Q1 silk label)

[image]

Comment: The trace solution works, if fact, looks nice. But if you call pins differently (VCC1 and VCC2 for instance), you still have the same line with the same name attached to them, the program will demand that you connect them.

Comment: I added an image to illustrate the unique pad numbers. I expect on your footprint 'tab' and 'pad 2' share the same name, e.g. 'VOUT' or 'C (ollector)'

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to avoid?

Yes. Copy the schematic symbol and modify it to have 4 pins, so that each of the two pins that are internally connected can be separately used as you wish. Then copy and modify the PCB footprint so that it has 4 pins as well, to match the schematic symbol. Done.

Some EDA systems supply such "separate pin" footprints and symbols, so it'd be prudent to check if maybe you don't need to do much but just use them :) In any case, the modification would be very simple to do.